# Which beer or beers are associated with Lent?

Tags: occasions

Are there any varieties of beer that some people associate with the liturgical season of Lent? If so, why?

Comment: I thought people stopped drinking during lent, so I was going to suggest "Alcohol Free" :p

Comment: @Atron  Perhaps in former days, but not any more. I drink during Lent. My bad!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bock style beers are regularly produced for festivals such as Christmas and Lent.

The specific kind of bock for Lent is Lentenbock.

The only one I've tried in the UK is Oates Lenten Bock.  It was a traditional Bock style, dark, sweet and strong and it was OK.  I wasn't enamoured of it enough to repeat tasting it.

Answer (score 1):

Found this little tidbit the other day: [Ten Weird Wonderful foods for Lent](http://www.firstthings.com/blogs/firstthoughts/2013/02/the-ten-most-wonderful-and-strange-foods-for-lent).

Rauchbier, or “smoke beer,” is made using malts that have been dried over fire—-thus gaining the smoky taste of cured meats like ham and bacon. At one time all beers malts were produced over fire, but in medieval Bavaria beers of this type came to be associated with Lent when the rich, smoky tones of meat were dearly missed. There is, of course, an official blessing for beer (“Bless, O Lord, this creature beer . . . ”) which one may safely assume is more efficacious in the original Latin: ” Benedic, Domine, creaturam istam cerevisiae, quam ex adipe frumenti producere dignatus es: ut sit remedium salutare humano generi, et praesta per invocationem nominis tui sancti; ut, quicumque ex ea biberint, sanitatem corpus et animae tutelam percipiant. Per Christum Dominum nostrum. Amen.  ”

Answer (score 1):

There was a brewer that went on a beer only diet several years ago.

[Here is the CNN article](http://religion.blogs.cnn.com/2012/02/25/my-take-what-i-learned-from-my-46-day-beer-only-fast/)

It was an interesting read and provides some backstory on why heavier beers are sometimes associated with Lent.

Comment: Could you bring the content of the link into your answer? This helps in case the link breaks in the future.